# Python request throws 400 when handling Graphql queries with variables

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to run graphql queries by using the built in requests module in Python.

```
# prepare the query with parameters
def get_user(by):
    try:
        variables = {
            "email": "test@test.com"
        }

        user_query = """
        {
          getUser($email:String) {
            userId
            email
            firstName
            lastName
            phoneNumber
            department
            officeLocation
            isAvailable
            updatedAt
          }
        }
        """

        path = resolve_url('users', site_id='hub')

        # Run gql query
        user_data = run_query(user_query, variables=variables, path=path, by=by)

        return user_data
    except Exception as ex:
        raise exc.BadRequest(
            'Could not parse the response. Following exception occurred :: {}'.format(ex)
        )
```

Client to run gql queries

```
def run_query(query: str, variables: dict, path: str, by=None):
    token = 'some-token'

    headers = {'x-internal-api-key': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)}

    json = dict({'query': query})
    if variables:
        json['variables'] = variables

    response = requests.post(path, json=json, headers=headers) # Throws 400

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception("Query failed to run: {} - {}".format(response.status_code, response.json()))
```

This throws `400 - {'message': 'Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $'...}`. The query works perfectly fine when passed a hardcoded value so no issues in the query itself.

Please help me in understanding where the issue is or suggest alternatives. I've gone through multiple links to figure out how to pass variables in the query but none seems to work.

Comment: It seems your requests parameter is not correct.

Comment: why do you think so? Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally figured out the issue. It seems that the variables must be declared to the query first and then used anywhere inside the graphql query. This is the fix:

```
    user_query = """
    >>>query($email: String!){<<<
      getUser(email: $email) {
        userId
        email
        firstName
        lastName
        phoneNumber
        department
        officeLocation
        isAvailable
        updatedAt
      }
    }
    """
```

Wish it was better documented somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well,If you really think your parameter is right.

There are two methods you can try(I don't make sure it will solve your problem,but you can try):

(Try to don't use `json` as variable,because it has the same name with a `json` module)
change your code for posting:

```
json = dict({'query': query})
response = requests.post(path, json=json, headers=headers)
```

to:

```
params = {'query':'''
  viewer {
     name
  }
}'''}

response = requests.get(path,params=params)
```

Maybe because query is a get method not a post method.(If not,you can try `post`)

Comment: Ok I did that. I've added the variables in the payload as well so the payload looks:
`payload = {'query': query, 'variables': variables}`

It still throws the same error.

If i remove the variables from the query & payload, it works as usual.

Comment: @saran3h Look carefully,Do you use `data` instead of `json` in the code?

Comment: @saran3h OK,I edit my post.Try to use a new method.

Comment: hmmm..strange that it works. When i hit the gql end point with Postman/insomnia, i use a POST and it works.

In any case my question is how to include variables in the query? I'm able to run my query just fine by removing $email variable, without changing anything in the given example.

Comment: @saran3h Sorry,I am not really know about gql.I just try my best to help you...

Comment: No worries mate. Thanks for the effort.